# How can I create globally-accessible modules in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

In Rails, I can create models which are global (accessible anywhere in the application). However, I'd like to create some constructs that are global, but don't correspond to any database table (which is why they can't be models) and won't ever be instantiated (so I need modules instead of classes).

I've tried using the initializers directory, which works, but is annoying because it requires restarting my server every time I change a value (whereas I can change the code in my models without restarting the server). What's the best way to create globally-accessible modules in this manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put it into `lib` sub-directory and add that to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding modules to the lib directory (which is appropriate), you can also put classes in the models directory.  They don't have to be ActiveRecord based.